# How to disable formatting for JavaDoc in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-14

I want to use style of JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Description.
 *
 * @param param1     parameter description
 * @param param2     parameter description
 * @return           return description.
 * @throws exception exception description.
 */
```

How you can see I want to use align to right description of parameters, returns and exceptions.

This style used at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

**So, my question:** how I can configured that style in **IDEA 2016.x.x** or how I can disable formatting for javaDoc without using specific comments `//@formatter:off` and `//@formatter:on`, if this possible?

Of course it's not serious and critical problem, but I am interest, because it's bad situation when developer can't set-up style by official documentation without any specific comment. I believe that i am wrong)

**PS:** I have tried off formatting at *File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->JavaDoc*, *Enable JavaDoc formatting* to *off* (and playing with all settings at this section). And my alignment on JavaDoc resets on *Ctrl-Alt-L*

Thanks for feedback!

Comment: I know it's not exactly your case, but if it's not the @param, etc. you can use html <pre></pre> tags.  Otherwise, you could possibly build a plugin to specify that format.

Comment: Setting _File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->JavaDoc, Enable JavaDoc formatting_ to off works well for me. I'm using version 2016.1.2

Comment: Aleksey, did you figure out how to do this? I'm trying to do something similar, and it keeps making the Javadoc template for me, even after turning the setting off.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the "Align parameter descriptions" setting do this automatically? [image: Screenshot right after applying setting]

Answer (score 0):

There are three plugins for intellij that might help:

- auto-align
- tabifier
- String Manipulation

For me, the **last one** seems to be best suited. When I formet text, I select the part of the text I want to be formatted, right click -> String Manipulation -> Align -> Align to Column.
Here, you have to experiment a little bit with the settings. It works for me.

See screenshot:
[image]
I added a space (the blue marker in the image) as a delimiter; selected a javadoc comment and used the above mentioned function. It works.